# Use of QTimer vs timer in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, qtimer

I am trying to wrap my head around how threads work in PyQt with Qtimer in a GUI app. Apologies for such a foundational question, but I've searched for other similar questions and failed to find informative answers.

I'm seeking to collect data from a series of sensors and process changes to the control structure based on the results. There is no user interaction required for this. However, there is a control panel of sorts and a series of status indicators that are intended to display as it runs. I have noted in other questions and examples that those using the normal time.sleep() function were typically directed to use QTimer instead.

In further digging I found the attached code example which works fine, using time.sleep(). As an object exercise, I attempted to replace this with various invocations of QTimer, none of which worked.

I also found references stating that QTimer can only work inside of QCoreApplication or similar. But the reason we're using Qtimer in the first place is that QApplication is running to support the GUI; without it we can't access any of the widgets. And without the GUI, we wouldn't need QTimer and could use time.sleep(), correct?

What am I missing here? Why does this code seem to work fine with time.sleep() when so many other examples seemed to require QTimer instead? If QTimer is used, how can that happen within QApplication?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime
import sys

class QCustomThread (QThread):
    startLoad    = pyqtSignal(int)
    progressLoad = pyqtSignal(int)
    statusLoad   = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__ (self, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QCustomThread, self).__init__(parentQWidget)
        self.wasCanceled = False

    def run (self):
        # Simulate data load estimation
        numberOfprogress = 100
        self.startLoad.emit(numberOfprogress)
        for progress in range(numberOfprogress + 1):
            # Delay
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if not self.wasCanceled:
                self.progressLoad.emit(progress)
            else:
                break
        self.statusLoad.emit(True if progress == numberOfprogress else False)
        self.exit(0)

    def cancel (self):
        self.wasCanceled = True

class QCustomMainWindow (QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(QCustomMainWindow, self).__init__()
        # Create action with QPushButton
        self.startQPushButton = QPushButton('START')
        self.startQPushButton.released.connect(self.startWork)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.startQPushButton)
        # Create QProgressDialog
        self.loadingQProgressDialog = QProgressDialog(self)
        self.loadingQProgressDialog.setLabelText('Loading')
        self.loadingQProgressDialog.setCancelButtonText('Cancel')
        self.loadingQProgressDialog.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModal)

    def startWork (self):
        myQCustomThread = QCustomThread(self)
        def startLoadCallBack (numberOfprogress):
            self.loadingQProgressDialog.setMinimum(0)
            self.loadingQProgressDialog.setMaximum(numberOfprogress)
            self.loadingQProgressDialog.show()
        def progressLoadCallBack (progress):
            self.loadingQProgressDialog.setValue(progress)
        def statusLoadCallBack (flag):
            print ('SUCCESSFUL') if flag else print ('FAILED')
        myQCustomThread.startLoad.connect(startLoadCallBack)
        myQCustomThread.progressLoad.connect(progressLoadCallBack)
        myQCustomThread.statusLoad.connect(statusLoadCallBack)
        self.loadingQProgressDialog.canceled.connect(myQCustomThread.cancel)
        myQCustomThread.start()

myQApplication = QApplication(sys.argv)
myQCustomMainWindow = QCustomMainWindow()
myQCustomMainWindow.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#msleep ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two important aspects you need to account for:

- `time.sleep` is *blocking*, QTimer is *not*.
- Q*Application is *event driven*, meaning that it waits for incoming events in its event queue, and should **never** be blocked, if not for *really* small amounts of time (usually the time required to execute a slot/function).

The problem with using blocking functions like `sleep` in the main Qt thread is that it doesn't allow the Qt application to process *any* event, no matter if it's a QApplication, a QGuiApplication or a QCoreApplication.

If a blocking function is called in the main Qt thread (no matter if the app is GUI driven or not), *everything* will be blocked and queued until that function returns, including *any* signal emission and consequent processing.

Note that this does *not* work in both ways when different threads are involved: if Qt detects that the sender and the receiver are in different threads, the signal is queued into the receiver event queue, and the sender thread returns `emit()` immediately.

Finally. If you have a separate thread that *actually* needs to wait for some time (usually needed within for/loop cycles to allow processing and avoid useless CPU calls with `pass`), use `time.sleep` or QThread's sleep functions (`sleep()` for seconds, `msleep()` for milliseconds, `usleep()` for microseconds).
If you don't need separate threads (meaning that the involved processing doesn't keep the CPU occupied), you can just use a QTimer (or, eventually, the static `QTimer.singleShot()`).

Comment: Thank you. I understood not using a blocking function in the main thread. If I understand correctly, you are endorsing the use of timer/sleep functions, if needed, in the secondary threads, which works here. Others seem to think QTimer is needed in those threads too.

However, I have also tried using Qtimer in the main thread and it doesn't wait. Adding a QTimer.singleshot() or QTimer instance with subsequent start() doesn't work if you place it at any point in the main thread. Researching this issue led me to the QCoreApplication discussion, which is incompatible with the GUI to begin with.

Comment: QTimer is needed in a thread whenever you need to do a timed event *in that thread* without blocking its processing, and as said it is *not* blocking: it is started in the thread in which it's created and only emits its `timeout` signal (calling the connected slots) for that thread. I don't understand the last half of your comment: QTimer works anywhere, including the main Qt thread, if it didn't work in your tests maybe you didn't connect it correctly or you tried to create a QTimer instance without a parent or a reference, which caused the timer to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Always remember native python thread is UNcompatitable with QT. Once you use QT, timer and internet connections, everything that includes another job must been done through the module of QT itself. The cause is that QT redefines a thread in C++ which is not compatible with CPython thread.